# In ADF Pipeline is there any trigger or method if a particular job is failed we have to run it again?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-workflow-automation

In ADF i have created workflows it means one workflow is dependent on other workflow like in this case for eg. 008_granular_--_model is dependent on 007_sow_retailersow_model. I am using event based trigger here. In every Execute_pipeline there is a databricks notebook that will be run.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBEgA.png)

problem is grower_churn_notebook is sometimes failing but i want campaign_inseason to be run succesfully. if any model fails, campaign_inseason should run perfectly.

Is there any way through which i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your image, you have set  campaign_inseason to run only if grower_churn finishes successfully. If you want it to run only when grower churn fails, connect it to the X (cross) endpoint instead of the tickmark endpoint.

[image]

You can also have it execute regardless of the outcome of grower_churn by connecting it to both the tickmark and the cross(X)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anand but there are 8 workflows which are dependent on each other. Let's suppose if 007th workflow fails then 008 will automatically fail. because 008 is dependent on 007th workflow

Comment: If you want workflow 8 to run inspite of workflow 7 failing, you can connect it to the X as my answer suggests. However if workflow 8 is dependent on some output of workflow 7 then ofcourse the entire workflow will fail. Maybe describe the scenario why you would want such a workflow to succsed in the first place.

Comment: can we can create a separate workflow to check if this job have ran for today or not, if not then only this job will be triggered to run

Comment: You can do this only if you know the unique run id which is generated per run per pipeline. If you have this you can use the ADF rest API to fetch the status of that particular runid